# Give certain values specific color in matrix with imagesc

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have a matrix A

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 
     1 0 0 1 0 0 1;
     1 0 0 0 0 1 1;
     1 0 1 0 1 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

And I want to give the 1's at the edges a specific color, and the 1's that are not at the boundaries a specific color and the 0's a specific color, How do I go about this?

Currently I just have `imagesc(A)`, I have been reading up on `colormap` and I do not understand it. To me it seems they just have set color scheme. On the website I see `winter`, `summer`, `hot`, `jet` etc. I would like to know how to modify, and how and where colors are displayed, and what colors are to be displayed.

Comment: you can do `cmap=winter` and save the colors in `cmap` to see them also. Its just a `Nx3` matrix, and MATLAB gives you some defaults, but any `Nx3` matrix will do. E.g. I create my random colors with `colormap(rand(N,3))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colormap in matlab allows you to set a color for an indexed image (in your case you only have 2 indexes - 0,1 which is usually interperted as black and white).
MATLAB has some predefine settings as you mentioned `winter`,`summer`, `hot`, `jet` etc.

You can define your own colormaps.In order to do that you need to first build a matrix of nX3 where n is the number of colors you need and the 3 is attributed to the RGB color space.

In your example above

```
imagesc(A)
```

Gives a blue and yellow image (since the default is `parula`).

If you define the new colormap matrix as follows

```
Cmap = [1 1 1; 0 0 0];
colormap(Cmap);
```

You will get the image in black and white (because of the values in Cmap). You can change the `Cmap` matrix values for different colors.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I have added more numbers to create a variation of `colormap` matrix for my needs.